# React Hooks. How to make other items(beside current one) deactivate when i click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, listitem

I have list of items.
What best practice to synchronize items,  when i click on one, other become deactivate?
So  active item can be only one of them at the same time?

My code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/deezer-music-widget-s4dli

Visual example of wrong case(2 active items)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbFHR.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea is to store the currently selected item in the parent list, and in the renderer pass an `active` or `selected` flag to the item which is selected. Conceptual example:

```js
function ListOfItems(props) {
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState();

  return (
    <ul>
      {props.list.map(item => (
        <ListItem
          key={item.key}
          active={item.key === selection}
          handleClick={setSelection}
          content={item.content}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

function ListItem(props) {
  return (
    <li
      className={props.active ? 'active' : null}
      onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.key)}>
      {props.content}
    </li>
  );
}
```

Comment: It works great! Thank you!

Comment: I knew it was something simple yet elegant. Spent 3 hours trying to figure out what I missed.

Thanks for the save!